# ListView not re-rendering items

Tags: react-native

RN: 0.32

hi guys need help. The ListView is inside a Modal and the data are fetched from API. The items in my ListView has an onPress, so when you click on an item, the icon beside it will change. But in my case, it doesnt update the icon unless i trigger a hot reload. I have other ListViews not inside a Modal and are fetching data from API and they're working fine using the same strategy. And also a ListView inside a Modal but not fetching data from API, also working fine. Only ListView inside a Modal and are fetching data from API that is not working. It will only update once i trigger a HOT reload. Its really weird, been working for this on for almost a day already. Really need help guys :(

This is the issue i submitted in facebook github
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11242

[image]

Comment: Can you submit an rnplay.org example, or at least provide the full code for this component instead of just screen captures?

Comment: hmm i dont know how to use rnplay.org. i can send u the file from where i took the screen caps. but i think its better you also see that scenario. i already saved a video capture for that but i cant send it here coz its file size is 20mb plus

Comment: can i email it to u instead?

Comment: For code, better you do a Github repo I can clone, or a Gist. For video, you can upload it to youtube or something.

Comment: let met try the youtube first. you take a look first whats your take. tnx by the way. really appreciate the time

Comment: sorry took long to upload. this is the youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ydH9q1F_G8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The fact that Hot Reloading updates your content is just a side effect that should not be taken into account. It merely tells us that the state is not updated somewhere in your component. Honestly, I can't help you much without the full code / flow of state of your component.

Comment: okay2. but the file is quite big. im currently using the Ignite boiler plate. hmm okay2 ill send it anyway. but i havent tried creating a repo yet